# What is the default servlet for OC4J?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oc4j

I need to know what is the default servlet in this application server (OC4J 10.1.3.3 is the exact version) because I am trying to deploy a web application made with spring mvc (The exact version is 3.1).

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler

And in my spring configuration file I use the following:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="unknown-oc4j-servlet-name"  />
```

In this container doesn't work if you not explicit writes the default servlet name

Comment: Not too familiar with oc4j, but did you try to find the "global" web.xml in the server config? That should include default servlet mappings.

Comment: Yes, I've found a mapping named, %OC4J_HOME%\config\global-web-application.xml, but there is no servlet for statics resources. There is a servlet named jsp for jsps but doesn't work, I think than the OC4J doesn't have a default servlet for statics resources..Is that possible?

Comment: Well, at the end , I've mapped the Spring Dispather instead of / to /mvc/* and works the resources statics inside the web folder are shown, another option is using mvc:resources but I have problems with the index.jsp

Comment: Not an entirely uncommon workaround.